# Rendering a large network (~4700 nodes and ~5500 edges)

Tags: cytoscape.js

Are there init options that are helpful for visualizing large networks? I've already set `hideEdgesOnViewport` and `hideLabelsOnViewport` to true, but the page still dies trying to load cytoscape.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Check your canvas dimensions.  Is your browser and device capable of rendering a canvas at that size?

(2) How much data are you putting in elements?  If you create lots of large objects and use lots of memory -- Cytoscape.js or no -- you can crash your page.

(3) Check the performance of your layout.  Try a very simple one like grid to isolate whether the layout is the issue.

(4) Try simplifying your style.  Try to load the graph with the default stylesheet but with haystack edges.  That should be pretty close to the fastest stylesheet possible.

(5) Read the notes regarding performance : http://js.cytoscape.org/#performance